# how to i apply black bootstrap to all my gridview and not just admin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gridview, yii

i am using black bootstrap as themes for mu application. the thinmg is it doesnt apply for other gridview expect the admin gridview .

i did try but unable to figure out therefore i am in need to know how can i access it.

please let me know

**http://yii.themefactory.net/theme/133/black-bootstrap#.UvntrmKSwkw**

is the extension where you can get idea of it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not allowing the default Yii styles to interfere with your CGridView. Set all the cssFile params to false:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$Model->search(),
    'filter'=>$Model,
    'pagerCssClass' => 'pagination',
    'itemsCssClass' => 'table table-bordered table-striped',
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'class' => 'container', // this is the class for the whole CGridView
    ),
    'pager' => array(
        'cssFile' => false, // Prevents Yii default CSS for pagination
    ),
    'cssFile' => false, // Prevents Yii default CSS for CGridView
    'columns' => array(
        array(
             'name' => 'your_column_name',
             'header' => 'Title for the Header',
             'headerHtmlOptions' => array(
                  'class' => 'class-for-header another-class-for-header',
             ),
             'htmlOptions' => array(
                 'class' => 'class-for-the-td',
             ),
        ),
    ),
    )) ?>
```

Also check the API docs for [CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView) and [CDataColumn](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataColumn) for all the options

Comment: sorry for late response. this has changed to look but not exactly the thing is the gridview has come out of th e container in which normally the gridbiew is and the header having the colum name is not black its white yet . and pagesize as specified 6 is not applying to the grdview .i need to know can we give the header colum name as black and the data rows as table stripped

Comment: Have edited my answer to include more options for classes etc. Also removed the pagesize stuff as that needs to be done inside your CActiveDataProvider - my mistake. The edits above should help you enough to fix it - and please read the docs I've linked, they're really useful!